# Who should our beta moderators be?

Tags: discussion, 7-questions, moderators

Robotics StackExchange has been in public beta for a week now, and soon it will be time for us to get our first crop of moderators, as explained in the [“Moderator Pro Tempore” blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/):

> About a week into the public beta, we will seek out members who are deeply engaged in the community’s development; members who:
>
> - Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
> - Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
> - Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
> - Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [*A Theory of Moderation*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Each beta site has (approximately) three moderators on a temporary, short-term appointment. Moderators Pro Tem focus and expedite the essential needs of each new site, both in terms of [regular moderator activies](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) and as a liaison of the growing community with the Stack Exchange team. By the end of Beta, the community will be better suited to hold their own elections.

Although the moderators pro tempore will ultimately be selected by Stack Exchange, the purpose of this post is to seek out and propose candidates:

- Each nomination should be posted as an answer and it should include (at minimum) a link to the user's main and meta profile so we can check out their activity.
- Self nominations are encouraged, step up if you feel you can help.
- If you are nominated by someone else you should edit the answer and let us know if you accept or decline (explanation optional). If a nominee declines we will not delete the answer, as to not have someone else nominate them again.
- If you are nominating someone else, please mark the post as Community Wiki before saving. Meta doesn't allow suggested edits, so your nominee may be blocked from accepting the nomination.
- The nominations are not binding to Stack Exchange or the nominees. If you are being considered by Stack Exchange, you will get an official confirmation email at one point.
- Before nominating someone or accept / decline a nomination, you should read [*A Theory of Moderation*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) thoroughly to find out what's generally expected from moderators.

If you would like to learn more about the role, please drop into [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6221/asimovs-corner) where you can ask about the role from other moderators (they appear with a blue name in the chat room). Another chatroom called [The Assembly](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2691/the-assembly) was created specifically for users and moderators to discuss moderation activities, moderators from all over the network are there to answer your questions.

Once again, **please don't hesitate to step up and self-nominate!**.

Comment: To give credit, I pretty much copied this from http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/113/who-should-our-beta-moderators-be. :)

Comment: To anyone else who thinks that they might have the time, energy and patience to help out as a moderator pro tempore, please feel free to nominate yourself.

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to nominate [Mark Booth](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/37/mark-booth) ([meta](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/37/mark-booth), [Network](http://stackexchange.com/users/18514/mark-booth) & [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/40660/mark-booth)) as a pro tem mod for this site. Mark has been participating in site-building for this site on area51 and has continued to do so on this meta. Besides, he seems to be well versed with the topic, as is evident from his contributions on main. He's also been around the network for pretty long -- so he probably is familiar with most policies.

[enter link description here http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/18514.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/18514.png)[image: enter link description here][image: enter link description here]

---

Thanks Manishearth, I would be happy to **accept the nomination** and help out with moderation during our beta period, at least until community elections can take place.

I worked in the robotics and mechatronics industry for around 6 years and worked in the laser scribing industry (more mechatronics) for another 6, so mine is a more industrial perspective, but I have recently started building my first [RepRap](http://reprap.org/wiki/RepRap). As such I'm starting to see robotics from a hobby perspective too.

I created the [Digital Fabrication](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41850/digital-fabrication?referrer=HAU0BHc85WMAKpA7nTzd4Q2) proposal over on Area 51 partially in response to the apparent difficulty in getting a *Robotics* proposal off the ground, but I am keen for *Robotics* to be the home to all levels of questions, from hobbyist through industrial to research.

I have been active on the stack exchange system for almost 4 years, and have 1k rep on 6 sites, so although I never been a moderator before I believe that I have a reasonable grasp of what is required of one.

I believe in [firm but fair moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/), and hope that my comments, edits and flags so far bear that out. I also hope that *Robotics* can be a [relatively tolerant](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15/37) so that we can build a thriving, vibrant community of roboticists.

Answer (score 6):

This post is both a nomination and an example of a nomination to get the rest of you started :)

---

I'd like to nominate myself, Mainshearth ([main](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/126/manishearth)|[meta](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/126/manishearth)), for this position.

[enter link description here http://se-flair.appspot.com/png/751483b5-3bd0-467a-b3aa-f0bb8ac3887d/](http://se-flair.appspot.com/png/751483b5-3bd0-467a-b3aa-f0bb8ac3887d/) [image: enter link description here] [image: enter link description here]

I'm Manish, a first-year engineering student. I've always had a passion for robotics, and for the past few months I've been working with others on various  robotics projects (brainstorming/design/fabrication ... everything). I'm no expert in Robotics, but it's going to take up a significant chunk of my attention for the next few years at least -- and I love the topic. Thus, I'm pretty interested in this site; I may not be able to contribute high-level answers, but I can certainly ask questions. And of course read through others' posts, I've learned quite a bit already from this site that way.

---

I'm a moderator on  [Chemistry.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/22/manishearth), so I know my way around the tools pretty well (as well as having participated heavily in site-building). I've also participated heavily on [the mother meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/178438/manishearth), so I'm quite familiar with most SE policies.

If I'm elected, I'd like to continue focussing on site-building (I'm more of a meta-person), as well as doing the standard moderator jobs (handling flags/approving edits/closing/editing/commenting --at this stage of the site, we don't have enough high-rep community members to handle these things).

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to nominate Rocketmagnet ([main](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/40/rocketmagnet) | [meta](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/40/rocketmagnet)) who has been very active on this site, during definition and since entering *beta*.

Clearly a man who knows the subject, and an asset to the site.

*I hope you feel able to accept this nomination*

[enter link description here http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/22610.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/22610.png)[image: enter link description here][image: enter link description here]

Comment: I'm happy to be a reserve if there aren't enough other people who want to be moderators. However, I can't vouch for my level of responsibility or amount of time available.

Comment: Thanks Mark... flag set (and apologies to RM)

Comment: Well, it didn't really matter in this case, because Rocketmagnet has edit rights anyways (1K rep)

Comment: @Andrew - I've just added [a nomination](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/a/139/37) for you, I hope that you are interested.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to nominate [ronalchn](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/145/ronalchn) ([meta](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/145/ronalchn), [Network](http://stackexchange.com/users/1723767/ronalchn) & [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/66506/)) as a [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) for *Robotics*.

*ronalchn* has been a very active participant in the beta so far, both asking and answering questions on *main* and participating on *meta*.

Although a relative newcomer to [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/users/1723767/ronalchn?tab=reputation), it is obvious from [recent activity](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/145/ronalchn?tab=activity&sort=all) that *ronalchn* has a pretty good idea about what makes a stack exchange site run well.

[Stack overflow flair http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1723767.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1723767.png)[image: Robotics stack overflow flair][image: Robotics stack overflow flair]

---

Thank you for your confidence in me. I do want Robotics to succeed. I have thought about it today, and although I would be willing to try this, I have a number of other commitments as well (working on my PhD, maintaining nztrain.com, and GitHub projects). While I have been somewhat active on StackExchange, I probably will not be able to maintain this level of activity over the next year (I have already spent less time on my GitHub projects). Therefore, **I would prefer if others with more time available step up**.

When I start feeling the pressure to finish my PhD, I am afraid I may find little time for much else. I am sorry I cannot offer more.

Comment: Thanks for the edit ronalchn, I completely understand being unable to commit to the time which may be required, I certainly had to think about it myself.

Answer (score 3):

The first time the question was asked, I was sure that we had plenty of well capable pro tempore moderators ready to go. Since the question has popped to the top of the list again (and looking through the nominations), it seems we are still a few moderators short. So I'm happy to put my own name ([main](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/131/thomash)|[meta](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/131/thomash)) forward.

[image: Stack Exchange network flair][image: Robotics flair][image: Meta Robotics flair]

Comment: _::telepathy::_ I was going to nominate you today, you've been pretty active on the meta and helpful on main. But you got there first. :)

Comment: @Manishearth - Ditto, ThomasH was the next person I was going to suggest too. We have a dearth of people who are active on meta, active on main and active on other stack exchange sites, so I've slowly been stalking my way through the user pages looking for people who might make good potential protems. *8')

Answer (score 1):

I would like to nominate [Andrew](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/134/andrew) ([meta](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/134/andrew), [Network](http://stackexchange.com/users/1769122/andrew) & [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/63742)) as a [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) for *Robotics*.

*Andrew* has been an active participant in the beta so far, participating on on both *main* and *meta*.

Although a relative newcomer to [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/users/1769122/andrew?tab=reputation), his activity on a variety of [different sites](http://stackexchange.com/users/1769122/andrew?tab=accounts) suggests that *Andrew* has a pretty good idea about what makes a stack exchange site work.

[Stack overflow flair http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1769122.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1769122.png)[image: Robotics stack overflow flair][image: Robotics stack overflow flair]

---

Many thanks to Mark for the nomination. After consideration, I have decided to gratefully **ACCEPT** the nomination, although as a relative Newbie to SE, I still have a lot to learn myself!

My background is as a 20+ year experience embedded systems engineer, working in the aerospace/defence world (flight control and missions systems) including work on the [Boeing/Cranfield X-48 UAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_X-48) and more recently in the automotive industry, working on cutting edge lithium (inc LiFePo4) battery management systems for hybrid and electric vehicles.

I'm also a member of the [MISRA Software Standards group](http://misra.org.uk/)

I'm dad to two young girls, and my other main interests are amateur radio and family tree research.