# Request to create synonym for not-exactly-c tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Could someone please add [nxc](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nxc) as a synonym for the [not-exactly-c](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/not-exactly-c) tag? NXC is an acronym of Not eXactly C, and is often used to refer to the language. I would do it myself if I had enough reputation.

Comment: Currently, the process of getting it done will be a bit unnecessary (we'll have to get a community team member in on this and all). Once we get protems, they'll be able to do tag merges/synonyms in a few clicks, so we can leave this meta post here for them for them to find. They also can do preemptive synonyming (I did a bunch of that when I was appointed on Chemistry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally tag synonyms are created when there is a problem with some people using one tag, some people using another, and some people using both. At this point, the tag synonyms are created and posts with either are considered the same for tagging purposes.

At the moment, we have a couple of [not-exactly-c](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/not-exactly-c) tagged questions and no [nxc](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nxc) tagged questions, so we aren't having a problem *yet*.

That's not to say it won't be a problem later, so it's good to bring these sorts of issues up, but I doubt it will be a priority for the stack exchange community moderators. When we get some [protem mods](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/84/37) though, they might be more likely to act on anticipated tag synonyms like this.